# How to manage thrift source file in version control?

Tags: version, versioning, thrift

We are currently exploring using thrift in our project. One of my question is how to handle the thrift source files and specific language generated files in version control (git) ?

Let's say I have project server A implemented using java, and project B an mobile application using Objective-C, and project C which is the thrift files. What currently on top of my mind is having all project as different git project, and project C as submodule of project A and project B. The pro is we can have consistent thrift source, and we don't need to put generated source files into git project.

Then let's say I have another thrift file that differs with project C, and being used only with project A and project D. Should I also put those files in project C? How project B knows that some files in project C not for him in case we put those files in project C?

Another approach might be committing the generated source files into each project. Or maybe another approach that I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought I understood Git thoroughly, but this question makes me second guess this assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of the musings about whether to split the projects in your highly specific case into Git submodules or not, these are the general guidelines that apply to all kinds of generated code, including Thrift, but not limited to it.

### General rules

1. The source documents (IDL, DSL, ...) belong into the repository.
2. Any code that can be easily generated out of these sources does not.

### Exceptions

As with nearly every rule, there are exceptions. The exceptions come in various flavours, such as

- the generated artifacts are not *easily* producable (for whatever reason)
- the generated code needs hotfixes to work around bugs <sup>1)</sup>
- etc.

### Additional notes

Strive to have one source, and one source only (of course not counting branches etc.) for these files. A good idea could be to set it up as a library to be used across projects. Treat that library like you would do with any other 3rdparty module, including proper versioning and all. If you use Git, indeed Git submodules *may* be an approach to achieve that.

> Then let's say I have another thrift file that differs with project C

If it differs, it is either a entirely different IDL, or a different version of the IDL in question.

---

<sup>1)</sup> In the real world, such things may happen. Unfortunately.